# Cassandra connection timed out causing by PasswordAuthenticator

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cqlsh

I am new to Cassandra, I have a problem connecting to it. Here is the detail:

1. Working Environment:
   Cubie-board A80, running Ubuntu Linaro 14.04 (which is download from http://dl.cubieboard.org/model/cc-a80/Image/ubuntu-linaro)
2. Cassandra version:
   Version 2.1.7 (from http://downloads.datastax.com/community/dsc-cassandra-2.1.7-bin.tar.gz)
3. Problem description:
   After running cassandra, when using cqlsh to connect to it (by typing `./cqlsh 192.168.10.26 -u cassandra -p cassandra`), it will timed out:`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.10.26': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection, last_host=None',)})`
4. Self-checking:
   In cassandra config file, listen_address, rpc_address and broadcast_rpc_address all set to 192.168.10.26, native_transport_port is 9042, which is default, start_native_transport is true.
   I also tried to run cqlsh without username and password, it showed:
   `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.10.26': AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires authentication.',)})`, which means cassandra is started.

Any idea what has happened? Thanks.

Updates:

Tried to specify 9042 port in cqlsh command;
Tried changing port number to 9043;
Tried checking port number 9042: in state 'LISTEN' and used by java;
Tried checking firewall status: no ufw installed

Update_new:
Problem narrowed down: it is the authenticator causing the problem, that is if I am using AllowAllAuthenticator, database will be connected without a problem; if I enable the PasswordAuthenticator, the connection timed out (using cassandra/cassandra as user_name and passwd). I know it is weird, exact same setting on my virtual machine does not show such connection problem.
Also tested in the latest stable version 2.2.3.

So far, problem solved: originally I was using OpenJDK on this Cubieboard, then I uninstalled the OpenJDK and switched it to Oracle Java, this problem solved by itself. Unfortunately, for now, I still do not know why the authentication will fail using OpenJDK but using Oracle will not. But this workaround might be helpful for those who use cassandra on Cubieboard A80.

Comment: Have you checked that your cassandra server's firewall is not blocking ports 9042 & 9160?

Comment: @Brandon, thank you for your suggestion, but the version of OS I am running on this new Cubieboard does not even have ufw installed.

Comment: Just to verify that no env variables or cqlshrc files are interfering, try specifying the port on the command line `cqlsh 192.168.10.26 9042 -u cassandra -p cassandra`

Comment: Where are you running `cqlsh` from?  Are you running it from the cassandra server itself?  Or remotely from another machine?  What version of `cqlsh` are you using `cqlsh --version`?

Comment: @Brandon, I tried from both same machine as well as another, does not make a difference. For cqlsh, I am using 5.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried increasing read_request_timeout?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal, Yes, I did, but it doesn't help. It doesn't feel like connection problem, but looks like some dependencies missed in this cubieboard ubuntu that make the authentication failed.

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your system logs associated with this? as in any errors reporting difficulties reading from system_auth.users? can you see if cassandra was created successfully? There should be a "Created default superuser 'cassandra'" in one of the nodes logs.

Answer (score 0):

Set broadcast_rpc_address to local IP and try setting rpc_address to 0.0.0.0

Comment: In the config file, it says "If rpc_address is set to 0.0.0.0, broadcast_rpc_address must be set".

Comment: I know - try commenting out broadcast_rpc_address anyway. By default, that value is not set.

Comment: I tried, but cassandra cannot start in this case: Fatal configuration error; unable to start.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. set broadcast_rpc_address to the local IP address and rpc_address to 0.0.0.0. Commenting out broadcast_rpc_address worked in c* 2.0.8 but not in 2.1.7. Does system.log have any helpful errors?

Comment: Just did exactly what you said, still got timed out when connect. Log file is normal, end with listening for thrift clients....Also, I changed the timeout setting in cofig, but it doesn't help.

Comment: try nodetool without specifying the IP address. try nodetool with 127.0.0.1 try netstat to see if there is a process is listening on 9042.

Comment: Please checkout my new update, I found out the source but still do not know reason.